# SlickNav - Open all items on single click (touch)

Tags: jquery, slicknav

On my Wordpress project I'm using SlickNav (http://slicknav.com/) as a main (top) menu.

How can I achieve that when user click (or touch, or opens) a menu, to show him all of the menu items, together with sub-items?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm thinking you could do this by writing a CSS rule that opens all subnavs if the first nav level is open. There are classes added to the elements when the user interacts- inspect element and click the button to see which class is added so that you can write your rule.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think this could be an answer:

```
<script>
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        jQuery(document).on('click','.slicknav_menu', function(e){
            jQuery('.slicknav_menu ul').show();
            jQuery('.slicknav_arrow').hide();
        })
    })
</script>
```